# Getting GCOverhead Limit exceeded

Tags: java, out-of-memory

The following code is throwing OutofMemoryError on Linux 3.5 enterprise box running jdk1.6.0_14 but running fine on JDK 1.6.0_20 I am clueless why its happening.

```
while (rs.next()) {
  for (TableMetaData tabMeta : metaList) {
rec.append(getFormattedString(rs, tabMeta));
  }
  rec.append(lf);
  recCount++;
  if (recCount % maxRecBeforWrite == 0) {
    bOutStream.write(rec.toString().getBytes());
    rec = null;
    rec = new StringBuilder();
  }
}
bOutStream.write(rec.toString().getBytes());
```

The getFormattedString() method goes here:

```
private String getFormattedString(ResultSet rs, TableMetaData tabMeta)
        throws SQLException, IOException {

    String colValue = null;
    // check if it is a CLOB column
    if (tabMeta.isCLOB()) {
        // Column is a CLOB, so fetch it and retrieve first clobLimit chars.
        colValue = String.format("%-" + clobLimit + "s", getCLOBString(rs,
                tabMeta));
    } else {
        colValue = String.format("%-" + tabMeta.getColumnSize() + "s", rs
                .getString(tabMeta.getColumnName()));
    }
    return colValue;
}
```

Below is the exception trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.justify(Formatter.java:2827)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2821)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printString(Formatter.java:2794)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2677)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2433)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2367)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2769)
        at com.boa.cpal.cpal2repnet.main.CPALToReportNet.getFormattedString(Unknown Source)
```

I suspect that the use of String.format is the culprit, but not sure. How to overcome this issue?

Please note that this code has been written to query on the database that have huge tables to read the resultset and create extract files with specific formatting.

Comment: I suspect the memory allocated to the heap via Xmx are different on both your JVMs? Or the JDK 1.6_20 is started with -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit ?

Comment: Actually the memory allocated on Windows is only 512M but on Linux, it is 1024M. No, the JDK on Windows was not started with -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit option.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't throw away the `StringBuilder` in the loop, but just clear it by calling [`setLength(0)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int)) this way the buffer does not need to be re-allocated each time. And frequent allocation and de-allocation is one common goal of the "GCOverhead Limit exceeded" problem.

Comment: There is very rarely a need to null a reference btw.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I used setLength(0) but that doesn't seem to improve the situation.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
        at com.boa.cpal.cpal2repnet.main.CPALToReportNet.writeDataToFile(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Amit why do you collect the strings in a stringbuilder? writing them with a BufferedWriter should have less overhead.

Comment: @Amit If the string grows large enough that it starts the gc then you should work with smaller parts. I had this problem working with a 300 MB big textfile, writing directly into the BufferedWriter got rid of 600 MB (the stringbuffer + complete string).

Comment: @josefx - Thanks, your suggestion to remove the use of StringBuilder and directly write to the file worked! I thought if i will write the file in bulk rather than one line at a time, it will perform better. But it turned out to be a memory hog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you are getting refers to the GC overhead limit that is enabled by this HotSpot option:

> -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -Use a policy that limits the proportion of the VM's time that is spent in GC before an OutOfMemory error is thrown. (Introduced in 6.)

So, my best guess is that your application is simply running out of heap space.  As @Andreas_D's answer says, the default heap sizes were changed between jdk1.6.0_14 and JDK 1.6.0_20, and that could explain the different behaviour.  Your options are:

- Upgrade to the later JVM.  (**UPDATE - 2012/06** even JDK 1.6.0_20 is now very out of date.  Later 1.6 and 1.7 releases have numerous security fixes.)
- Explicitly set the heap dimensions -Xmx and -Xms options when launching the JVM.  If you are already doing this (on the older JVM), increase the numbers so that the maximum heap size is larger.

You could also adjust the GC overhead limit, but that's probably a bad idea on a production server.

If this particular problem only happens after your server has been running for some time, then maybe you've got memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I have changed the command to run my program as follows:

java -server -Xms100M -Xmx1024M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 

This caused the program to work fine for some time but later on it failed with following OutOfMamoryError:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
       ....

Looks like there is issue with the code too other than the java options. I could not allocate more that 1400M to heap due to physical memory limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection has been improved significantly with JDK 1.6.0_18:

> In the Client JVM, the default Java heap configuration has been modified to improve the performance of today's rich client applications. Initial and maximum heap sizes are larger and settings related to generational garbage collection are better tuned.

A quick look at the details in this [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html) makes me believe that this is why you have less problems with 1.6.0_20.

---

The following part of the code is not consistent with the comment:

```
// Column is a CLOB, so fetch it and retrieve first clobLimit chars.
colValue = String.format("%-" + clobLimit + "s", getCLOBString(rs, tabMeta));
```

`colValue` doesn't get the first `clobLimit` bytes from the CLOB, it is left-justfied at the *column* `clobLimit`. I wasn't sure and tried

```
 System.out.println(String.format("%-5s", "1234567890"));
```

and the output was

```
 1234567890
```

To achieve what you tell in the comment, you can use the simpler form:

```
colValue = getCLOBString(rs, tabMeta).substring(0, clobLimit);
```

Comment: That looks correct as the application is running fine on 1.6.0_20. I will try to get the latest JDK installed on the Linux box, though its not in my hands :(

Comment: I there something in the code that I can improve to fix this?

Comment: Ya the comment verbiage is misleading. Actually the getCLOBString(rs, tabMeta) method itself fetches only "clobLimit" number of characters. String.format has been used to ensure right paddin to make all values of a column equal in length.